# Get diameter of circle from bitmap rectangle

Tags: c#, geometry, computational-geometry

i have a bitmap and i want to rotate it around its center for a full 360 degrees. while doing so, the bitmaps rectangle will transcribe a circle.

i would like to know the diameter of that circle. what is the best way to accomplish that in C#. we cannot save each rotated bitmap to drive so it has be all in-memory given a starting bitmap.

Comment: That would just be the diagonal measure of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal of a rectangle inscribes a circle diameter when it is rotated. So we can calculate the diameter using the following formula:
Sqrt (Width<sup>2</sup> + Height<sup>2</sup>)

So in C#:

`Math.Sqrt(image.Width * image.Width + image.Height * image.Height)`